# Android: Nav Drawer back button can't finish application

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm working on app which using nav drawer. Unfortunately I can't figure out, how can I finish this application, when user press back button  in main screen? I'm trying to override back button and there finish my activity, but this doesn't work. The activity finish and starts again and again..

I was trying more examples like:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or override

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {            
        finish();
    }
```

// EDIT
there is my main activity code, most of it is generated by Android Studio:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, boolean fromSavedInstanceState) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, EmailListFragment.newInstance(position))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Should close application when back button is pressed, but  doesn't work yet
     *
     * @param keyCode
     * @param event
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            this.onDestroy();
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is already the default behavior, so you shouldn't need any of this code. Are you using the emulator? I've seen it act up like this before. If I understand your problem correctly, if you try it on a physical device, it shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this happens on my hw (nexus 4) too. Just when I press back button it finish current activity and start new activity (deafault) again.

Comment: I have a feeling this is an IDE problem... However, have you tried calling super.onDestroy() before finish()?

Comment: Doesn't work error: nable to pause activity {package...activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity

Comment: Sorry, I meant this.onDestroy().

Comment: same result :-( btw: my old app whre I'm also using nav drawer works correctly and I can't find any difference :D

Comment: I guess post more of your code, then. Sorry my suggestions didn't work. Maybe there's just something small you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the code - which makes sense, since most of it was from a template - except my suggestion of using onDestroy. It's gotta be Android Studio. I'd try sideloading the APK or creating a new project and copying the code over. If neither of those works, it's got to be a bug. Since it'd have to be in the Activity, I'd try extending Activity instead of ActionBarActivity (which limits you to SDK v14+), because that avoids using the support library, removing a variable from the problem.